# how to map a gtk window to data

Tags: gtk

We're writing a diagnosis tool using GTK. You should watch several properties of different ojects, each in an own window. So you should be able to open several equal windows, each 'attached' to a specific object. When for example a button is clicked the appropriate GTK callback is called. But since all windows are equal there is no natural way to see which object should be altered. How could we map each window to its object in a good way? 
Right now we use a map, mapping from the gtk windows to an object, but that feels more like a hack. Can we hand over the information about the object in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GtkWindow` is an indirect subclass of `GObject`, so you can use the family of functions `g_object_set` and `g_object_get` (and `g_object_set_data`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the team mentioned above looking for a solution. Here is what I got to work so far: I create a Gvalue object and want to add it to `GTKWindow window`.

```
int pid = 12345;
GValue val = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init (&val, G_TYPE_INT);
g_value_set_int (&val, pid);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT(window), "pID", &val, NULL); //add to GTKWindow
```

When pressing a button in this window the following signalfunction is used:

```
extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT void onButtonStepClicked(GtkObject* caller, gpointer data){
    GValue _pid;
    GtkWidget* window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel (GTK_WIDGET(caller));
    g_object_get_property(G_OBJECT(window), "processID", &_pid);
    cout << (int)g_value_get_int(&pID) << endl;
}
```

But now i get the warning to my terminal:

GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class `GtkWindow' has no property named`pID'

So i googled a while and found an example where i first have to install this Properties to a class. Does this makes sense, or did i miss something here?

Comment: This is the place for an answer, not a question. BTW, I this your problem is that you set a "pID" property and try to retrieve a "processID" property.

Comment: yep, this was only a typing issue, while editing this wrong positioned (sry) question. The problem still remains.

But you meant, normally this should work?

Comment: From the documentation, g_object_get_property is of use only for bindings. You should use g_object_get and g_object_set instead. I'm no GObject expert, but I think you need to create the property before being able to get/set it. See g_object_class_install_property and g_object_class_install_properties in GObject documentation.